# Node.js and Express handlebars - 404 Error

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

For my class I have to design an app that says at the top of the page whether an incoming request is GET or POST, then has to print a table that shows all parameter names and values that were sent in the URL query string, and the property names and values that were received in the request body.
So far I have been able to get my localhost:port to work, it correctly shows whether a request is GET or POST. But when I go to the subpage that is supposed to display the tables, I get a 404 instead.

Here is the render page that I think is causing the problem:

```
function runQ(req) {
  console.log(req.qParams);
  console.log(req.body);

  var context = {};
  context.queryParams = [];
  context.bodyParams = [];
  context.queryCount = 0;
  context.bodyCount = 0;

  for( var p in req.qParams) {
    context.queryCount++;
    context.queryParams.push({'name': p, 'value': req.qParams[p] });
  }

  for( var p in req.body) {
    context.bodyCount++;
    context.bodyParams.push({'name': p, 'value': req.body[p] });
  }

  context.methodType = req.method;
  return context;
}

app.get('/request', function(req, res) {
  res.render('request', runQ(req));
});
app.post('/request', function(req, res) {
  res.render('request', runQ(req));
});
```

I have a request.handlebar saved in my ubuntu/getpost/views folder along with the 404 and 500 handlebars.

The command I use for testing is:

```
$ curl --data "a=1&b=2&c=3" localhost:port
```

I replaced the localhost:port with an actual IP and port address when I have node running.
My console returns this on the tab that is running node:

```
undefined
{ a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
```

And this on the tab where I typed the cURL command:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Demo Page</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h1>POST Request Received</h1>

  <table>
    <caption><p>Request Body Table</p></caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Property Names</th>
        <th>Values</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>c</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

So everything seems to be working from the console but when I try to access localhost:port/request, I go to the 404 error instead of a page that displays the tables.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you all for your time.

Comment: I don't see any route specified for `/request`.

Comment: I thought these route the page to /request:  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('request', runQ(req));
});
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('request', runQ(req));
});

Comment: `/` will only match the root of your app. You could technically use regex and other options that express provides to parse the url. But normally, when you request `/request`, express expects there to be `/request` route defined to it. You can find more examples and options in the [doc](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Comment: Thank you, I went over the document you linked, and based on what I was able to gather there, I revised my code to app.get('/request', function(req, res) {
  res.render('request', runQ(req));
});
app.post('/request', function(req, res) {
  res.render('request', runQ(req));
}); But that simply moved my homepage from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/request.  I am not sure how I can get those two tables to show up that display the results.  Any tips?

Comment: Hm, that's strange. It shouldn't redirect automatically to `/request` when you're just request for `/`. Can you update the post with what you have right now?

Comment: Nevermind, there was a syntax error in my code, and I managed to resolve it.  Thank you so much for your help!